# Why i'm getting [object object] using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function there i want to try sum two numbers using variable like given below, but i'm getting [object object] instead of total of sum.

```js
 
var convenienceCharge = 100;
var totalPgCost = 500;
var subTotalPgCost = 0;

function totalPgCostFunction() {

subTotalPgCost += $('.subTotalPgCost').text(convenienceCharge +  totalPgCost + 18);

alert(subTotalPgCost);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="totalPgCostFunction();">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text` will return a object. that is why you are seeing [object object]

You need to do it like this.

```js
var convenienceCharge = 100;
var totalPgCost = 500;
var subTotalPgCost = 0;

function totalPgCostFunction() {

subTotalPgCost += convenienceCharge +  totalPgCost + 18;

$('.subTotalPgCost').text(subTotalPgCost);
alert(subTotalPgCost);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="totalPgCostFunction();">Click</button>
<div class="subTotalPgCost"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because when you call the setter of `text()` it returns a jQuery object, hence the output you see.

To make this work you need to split the calculation and `text()` logic, like this:

```js
var convenienceCharge = 100;
var totalPgCost = 500;
var subTotalPgCost = 0;

$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    subTotalPgCost += convenienceCharge + totalPgCost + 18;
    $('.subTotalPgCost').text(subTotalPgCost);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click</button>
<div class="subTotalPgCost"></div>
```

Also note the use of an unobtrusive event handler in this example instead of the outdated `on*` attribute.

Comment: That may be nit-picking, but _"...because text() returns a jQuery object..."_ is only true for the case when calling `.text()` with an argument.

Comment: Nit-picking is good - it ensures accuracy :) and you're right. I've updated the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Are you the OP? I am confused. Also, what's the error?

Comment: Who are you? You're not the OP, and I'm not going to amend someone's random answer.

Comment: The person who asked the question

Comment: You're not new here, though. You've been here nearly a year and already answered 15 questions. Are you using a shared account?